# How do I count() only the distinct values on a specific field when returning a queryset

Tags: django

I have a function that returns a queryset that is a list of records that I would like to return the count() of the records which it does BUT I want to only count the distinct values from a specific field.  I can easily do this in a SQLite query but cant seem to get it in Django.

**Here is the SQLite Query that works BUT I need to do this in a Django View:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Host FROM inventory_scandata WHERE Project_Assigned LIKE '%Hooli%' AND Environment LIKE '%PROD%'
```

**Here is my current function that returns the non-distinct count:**

```
def HooliProject(request):
    prodAssets = ScanData.objects.filter(Q(Project_Assigned__icontains="Hooli_1") & (Q(Environment__icontains="PROD")))
    prodAssetsHosts = prodAssets.distinct()
    prodAssetsDistinct = prodAssetsHosts.distinct()
    prodAssetsCount = prodAssetsDistinct.count()
    context = {
        'prodAssets': prodAssets,
        'prodAssetsCount': prodAssetsCount
        }

    return render(request, 'HooliProject.html', context)
```

Comment: Share the relevant model(s). Especially the `ScanDate` and `Host` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is `count()` the distinct values of `Host` field, you can use `values('Host').distinct().count()`, so you're using [`distinct()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) in conjunction with [`values()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-fields).

```
ScanData.objects.filter(
    Q(Project_Assigned__icontains="Hooli_1") & Q(Environment__icontains="PROD")
).values('Host').distinct().count()
```

Below is your code with the additions where needed.

```
def HooliProject(request):
    prodAssets = ScanData.objects.filter(Q(Project_Assigned__icontains="Hooli_1") & (Q(Environment__icontains="PROD")))
    prodAssetsHosts = prodAssets.values('Host') # <--- I've changed here ;D
    prodAssetsDistinct = prodAssetsHosts.distinct()
    prodAssetsCount = prodAssetsDistinct.count()
    context = {
        'prodAssets': prodAssets,
        'prodAssetsCount': prodAssetsCount
        }

    return render(request, 'HooliProject.html', context)
```

Also if you're on PostgreSQL you can use `distinct('Host').count()`.

> On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should apply. This translates to a SELECT DISTINCT ON SQL query. Here’s the difference. For a normal distinct() call, the database compares each field in each row when determining which rows are distinct. For a distinct() call with specified field names, the database will only compare the specified field names.

Answer (score 0):

To get distinct values in SQLite, you need to use a set(). Check the example below.

```
queryset = set(ScanData.objects.values_list('Project_Assigned', flat=True).filter(Project_Assigned__icontains='keyword'))
```

You can also do:

```
queryset = set(ScanData.objects.values_list('Project_Assigned', flat=True)).count()
```